# Regular Expression for this text

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a `regex` for extracting numbers from the following text (that is part of a bigger text):

```
 switchport trunk allowed vlan 206,220,23,234,250,262,21,283,2086,296,305,323
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 334,340,342,365,380,404,41,414,42,421,434
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 461,472,499,509,29,535,544,551,552,55,595
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 642,672,690,697,701,704,711,800,2018,2020
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 2054
 switchport mode trunk
```

I want to extract all the vlan numbers between **switchport trunk allowed vlan** and **switchport mode trunk**

I think that the pattern should be like:

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan (\S*) ((\d+),*)+(?:.|\n)
```

but don't know how to extract the other numbers (only the first one matched)

I use the pattern in `PHP` in `preg_match` function.

Comment: I think you want this:- https://eval.in/596968

Comment: Or may be this:- https://eval.in/596974

Comment: Please up-vote the answer too if not done yet.thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To extract all the numbers, so you can do it in following manner:-*

```
<?php
$str = ' switchport trunk allowed vlan 206,220,23,234,250,262,21,283,2086,296,305,323
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 334,340,342,365,380,404,41,414,42,421,434
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 461,472,499,509,29,535,544,551,552,55,595
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 642,672,690,697,701,704,711,800,2018,2020
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 2054
 switchport mode trunk'; // original string
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches); // check for all digits and make array $matches
print_r($matches); // print digits array
echo implode(',',$matches[0]); // convert digits array into comma separated string of numbers
?>
```

Output:-  https://eval.in/596968   OR  https://eval.in/596974

*Note:- this will work for single-line,multi-line,paragraphs as well (if your complete data is in a single variable).*

Answer (score 1):

This will print each match, the array $matches[0] has all of the values.

```
$str=' switchport trunk allowed vlan 206,220,23,234,250,262,21,283,2086,296,305,323
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 334,340,342,365,380,404,41,414,42,421,434
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 461,472,499,509,29,535,544,551,552,55,595
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 642,672,690,697,701,704,711,800,2018,2020
 switchport trunk allowed vlan add 2054
 switchport mode trunk';

preg_match_all("/([0-9])\w+/", $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $val) {
    echo $val.'<br>';
}
```